# How Do I Stop the Native Podcast App from Removing Played Episodes?

Tags: podcasts.app

I often listen to podcasts as I fall to sleep.  The result is a podcast may finish playing without me actually having finished it.  The annoying thing is the Podcast then *removes* the episode thinking it's played & no longer needed.

Is there a way to stop this behavior.  I would rather the app simply keep the last X episodes, regardless if it believe they had been listed to or not?

I know I can add them back, but it's somewhat tedious to keep doing that.

I tried looking in both the settings for the Podcast app & while it's connected to iTunes, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes on the computer when the iOS device is connected choose the device in the sidebar. This will goive a page with a menu on top allow select od Podcast. Like this
[image]

The second oval shows that I have selected to sync podcasts automatically keeping the 5 least recent unplayed.

Alter these options to either keep updates manual or choose new rather than unplayed.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't check there!  *forehead slap*  Thanks!